# I am having an "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (id = "path")" error

Tags: r

I am working on a dataset at my first day of work, and I am trying to run this block of code

```
df <- list.files(path = "mypath", full.names = TRUE) %>%
  lapply(read_csv, col_names = TRUE, col_types = cols(.default = "c"), 
         id = "path") %>%....(more code)
```

While this code works for every other colleague of mine, it does not work on my computer (they all use Macbook while I use Windows. We all run our code in RStudio.) The error is that

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (id = "path")

When I deleted id = "path", I have to face a new error: object 'path' not found"

When I asked the colleague who wrote this code why path was in there (as lapply does not have a variable called ID according to rdocumentation), he said that "Id is the folder name." Since he quitted the company and wrote this code long ago, he did not know why he used this ID variable.

So I am stuck. Can someone take a stab at this ?

Comment: I would simply take the `id` argument out. If that gives you the expected list of data frames, you can pipe the result to `setNames("my path")`

Comment: I think the markup for your question got messed up—I’m assuming you didn’t mean the last paragraph to go in the quote block?

Comment: Is "mypath" a valid path on your machine? Try `list.files("mypath")`. Do you see the files you are supposed to be reading?

Comment: Only way I can see why code fails for you is a different version of `readr` where `read_csv` does not yet support `id`.